# Android Play Store Campaign tracking pre-requisites

Tags: android

I'm attempting to use a campaign to promote my application.  I've found these instructions and am attempting to do step one:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/campaigns#google-play-campaigns

However, my IDE (IntelliJ) is telling me it cannot resolve "com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingService" in the Manifest file.

Is this a Bug in the IDE?  Or is there a library I'm meant to be including with my application?  And are there any other steps they have missed out?  E.g. do I need to be adding internet permissions to my application?

When I run the application it seems to work fine, and here is my Android Manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_toddlerswords"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity android:name="maddy.toddlercolors.ToddlerWords"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="maddy.toddlercolors.menu.QuickPrefsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"/>

    <!-- Used for install referral measurement-->
    <service android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingService"/>
    <receiver android:name="com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further reading it looks like campaign tracking requires a google analytics jar, and will require internet permissions.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/